# Unable to get an error from the array with getID3

Tags: php, arrays, getid3

I'm trying to get an error to return when I search the temporary file that is uploaded.

`

```
$getID3 = new getID3;
$file = $getID3->analyze($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
//print_r($file);

if (isset($file['error'])) {
    echo $file['error'];
} else {
    echo "
    <b>Duration:</b> " . $file['playtime_string'] . "<br/>
    <b>Dimensions:</b> " . $file['video']['resolution_x'] . "x" . $file['video']['resolution_y'] . "<br/>
    <b>Filesize:</b> " . $file['filesize'] . "bytes";
}
```

`

And it exists in the array because when I upload an invalid file type it returns this array.

```
Array
        (
            [GETID3_VERSION] =&gt; 1.9.12-201602240818
            [filesize] =&gt; 159924
            [filepath] =&gt; /tmp
            [filename] =&gt; phpQAJeuD
            [filenamepath] =&gt; /tmp/phpQAJeuD
            [encoding] =&gt; UTF-8
            [error] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [0] =&gt; unable to determine file format
                )

        )
```

How is it not getting `['error']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`['error']` is an array.

You need to output `['error'][0]`

Comment: Yea I won't lie, RIGHT when I posted this I literally saw my problem... I really should head to bed LOL.

Anyways thanks :P, apologies for terrible post :) Enjoy free answer

EDIT: Have to wait 8 mins

Answer (score 2):

Because `$file['error']` is an array. Arrays cannot be echoed.

You can print the contents of an array by using the function `print_r()` or by looping trough it.

For example:

```
$arr = array('one', 'two', 'three');
foreach($arr as $value){
    echo $value."\r\n";
}
```

See the php documentation on Arrays for more information on how to handle them: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

If in any case you are not sure what the type of a variable is, you can resolve that by using the function `gettype()`. Also see the documentation for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php

Comment: Yea, I realized my error right when I posted this and didn't delete it in time. So my apologies

Comment: @CameronSwyft No worries.